# Filtering a binding list, binding doesn't work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In a grid i use a binding list to bind data:

```
childBindingSource.DataSource = 
               db.Child.Local.ToBindingList()
                             .Where(child => selectedrow != null 
                                             && child.MasterID == selectedrow.ID)
                             .ToList();
```

Or without filter:

```
childBindingSource.DataSource = db.Child.Local.ToBindingList();
```

If I filter the binding list using a where expression, saving data doesn't work,yet i do not get any exceptions.

Any ideas?

Row click event for getting child records:

```
    private void gridView1_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedrow = gridView1.GetFocusedRow() as Master;

        if (selectedrow != null)
        {
            int id = selectedrow.ID;
            db.Child.Where(child => child.MasterID == id).Load();
        }


        childBindingSource.DataSource = db.Child.Local.ToBindingList();

    }
```

Comment: What is `ToBindingList`?

Comment: Keeps the local data with the grid's datasource in sync.

Comment: Does the second LOC work?

Comment: Yup.Just filtering the data messes up everything.

Comment: Did you try calling `ToBindingList` after the `Where` filter?

Comment: There is lexical ambiguity in your sentances... What I read is that saving works if you don't filter. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep,db.savechanges() to be precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DbSet.Local` is an `ObservableCollection`, so you can use `ToBindingList()`, and data binding with a grid is a smooth operation.

`ToList` just creates a `List<T>` and data binding does not communicate additions and removals from the list (I expect updates to work though).

The remedy is to filter the data that the context loads into the `Local` list:

```
db.Child.Where(child => selectedrow != null 
                     && child.MasterID == selectedrow.ID).Load();
childBindingSource.DataSource = db.Child.Local.ToBindingList();
```

That means that you have to use a new context for each set of child records you show and update.

Comment: Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'lazyloading.Master'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.  Any ideas?

Comment: Take the check `selectedrow != null` outside the query and use a variable `var id = selectedrow != null ? selectedrow.ID : 0` and use `id` in the query.

Comment: Cheers,however the filtering doesn't work.In my details grid,all records are selected....

Comment: Maybe you should ask a new question now. I need more details to see what's going on here.

Comment: As I said, you need a new context each time. Now you keep adding records to the Local list.

Comment: clearing the local wont work? well, tried doesnt work,however isnt there any other way? :)

Comment: No, that marks entities as `Deleted`. You can detach the child entities though: loop through the list and set state `Detached`.