# How do I refresh all my entities with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework for one of my projects and in my solution, I have currently 2 DbContexts I'm using.

The first one is pretty much read-only, it contains the whole database. The other one is a subset of the first one, it contains part of the data (same structure) and that one is editable.

I have two forms, one that display the whole data in read-only mode and another one that edits a small subset (its hierarchical data, double clicking in one row opens the whole branch basically).

Now, once my edit form closes, I want the firm form to display the new changes also.

How can I refresh my context so it queries the database again ? I don't want to drop it and then re-create it since when I do so, the grid control does not behave correctly.

I read that I can refresh certain entities, but in that context, I might not be aware that there is a new entity created (I would if they were deleted or removed). Also note that once the edit form closes, the changes are pushed to the database, thanks to the second DbContext.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say the reason you might not be getting much of a reply is because of the (unusual?) way you are using two DbContexts. I've never done that before, and I'm having a hard time understanding the need or justification for it. Off hand, without a better understanding, it seems like you are making like harder for yourself by doing this.

Comment: Maybe! I'm really new to Entity and still haven't found how to use it correctly, I'm just patching through it. The reason I'm using two contexts is because I need to select a subset of my data, not the whole data. I tried using a stored procedure to select my specific data, but it seems Entity does not handle select statements like Dataset technology does. I tried using `Where` clause in my dbset, but then I can't create a `BindingList` for my control. Therefore, I'm trying multiple context instances like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31702094)